# Array is null in xcode

Tags: mysql, ios, xml, xcode, core-data

I have been trying to send data down in xml format to the iphone. But I just cannot get the array to properly work. NSLog keeps returning null. What should I do to correct this?

```
<?php
...(mysql query)
$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$r = $doc->createElement( "oneam" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );
foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $e = $doc->createElement( "location" );

    $e->setAttribute( 'its', $row['oneam']);

    $r->appendChild( $e );

}
print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

My Xcode for a view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    char *cStr = "YES";
    NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cStr];


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(censored)", _login];

    NSXMLParser *Parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
    [Parser setDelegate:self];
    [Parser parse];


    if (([[oneam objectForIndex:@"its" ]isEqualToString:@"YES" ])) {
            [switch1 setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
            [switch1 setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"location"]) {
        [oneam addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict]];
    NSLog(@"The array is %@", oneam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad` write the following code:

```
oneam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You are not allocating the array, that's why it is null.

Comment: Great! While I've got you, my objectForIndex is not a recognized method for my array some reason... (gotta wait 8 min to give you the check)

Comment: It should be `objectAtIndex:`.